# How to retrieve values from an Xml as Objects but not Strings?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, casting, linq-to-xml

I have some code that parses an xml file using `XDocument`.

It retrieves the values correctly but some of the values I save to xml is of type `Object`. So when I read these values from the xml, they come as `string` values, even though I cast them as objects:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load ( file );
XElement xe = doc.Element ( "EffectFile" );

xe.Elements ( "Options" ).Any ( )
    ? xe.Elements ( "Options" ).Select (
        o => o.Elements ( "Option" ).Select (
            n => ( object ) n.Value ).First ( ) )
    : null ) )
```

The value as it appears in the xml:

```
...
<Option>88</Option>
...
```

comes as `"88"`, instead of `Object 88`.

I understand that when I cast a `string` to an `Object`, it will still be a `string`, but is there a way to make it an `Object` of the actual value (whatever that might be) but not a `string`?

Because these are different, isn't it?:

```
object value = 88;
object value = (object) "88";
```

and later when I use my `options` value stored as `object[]`, I want to be able to do:

```
int intValue = (int) value;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML holds strings - if you are sure what you are keeping in what places in your xml, you can parse it to correct type - like Tony Casale wrote for ints.

Or if you can have any objects in some places, you'd have to add attribute which specifies to your xml reading code, to what type this node should be changed after reading.

like this:

```
<option>
     <name>some name</name>
     <value type="int">123</value>
</option>
<option>
     <name>some other name</name>
     <value type="string">abcdefg</value>
</option>
```

Then in your code you will have to check which type to convert each string from value tag.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But is using type="" the only way? I just want to save my object[] values the way they are, and not object string values, but whatever they were before. So for this I have to store the types in the xml? When doing "automatic" xml serialization, I noticed the serializer using something like <anyType>value</anyType>. Maybe that's how they do it?

Comment: Xml can be wrote to disk as text file, so if type isn't specified, there is no way to whatever program reads it from the disk to know which type it was before. It don't have to be attribute - it can be another element nested in the value element, or it can be attribute with other name, but some hint to the reader is needed.

Comment: @Joan - if you read them from XML then they will always be strings.

Answer (score 3):

Yes those are different.  You need to do:

`int intValue = int.Parse("88");`

If you don't know what the source type is, you can also do:

`int intValue = Convert.ToInt32(someObject);`

Which will convert anything to an `int`, if it can.

Comment: Thanks but I want to be able to retrieve the value from the xml in a way that will allow me to use int intValue = (int) value; Otherwise I am not able to preserve the same values through saving/loading, i.e. having an int before and now a string.

Comment: You won't be able to use `(int)value` unless `value` is already an int.  The `Convert.ToInt32()` method should work for you, if I understand correctly.

Comment: @Joan: if you store `intValue` in an `object[]` after either parsing or converting, it should work.

Comment: Thanks, so do you know how I can store and retrieve the actual object value = 88; as an int just like it was before? Basically this is just the int values, but since my Options property is of type object[] I want to retrieve the values correctly just like I had them in code, i.e. int, string, Font, etc.

Comment: @Joan: you need some way of knowing what type the value was when you stored it, like an attribute in the tag (see @ajuc's answer). Depending on your need you may be interested in serialization.

Comment: Thanks I had some issues with serialization and also needed a custom formatting, so used XElements, etc. I guess I will have to store the type then.

Answer (score 2):

XElement has an operator overload for explicit int cast, so you probably should be doing that

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load ( file );
XElement xe = doc.Element ( "EffectFile" );

xe.Elements ( "Options" ).Any ( )
    ? xe.Elements ( "Options" ).Select (
        o => o.Elements ( "Option" ).Select (
            n => ( int) n).First ( ) )
    : null ) )
```

Comment: Thanks, but the values I have can be of any type, hence I have them in code as object[] values.

Comment: @joan-venge You have to know at the time you are walking through the file whether the values are ints or not. XML is all strings you have to have some indication in the format to determine whether you want to use it as number or not and then convert accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

XML is text... it is normally returns values of nodes as text. As jbtule said you can use explicit casts (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348319.aspx) for details.

You may also consider using XML serialization instead of reading raw XML.